# At which point becomes a changed computer group membership active?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

When adding a computer object to an AD group, at which point in time does the group membership become active? Is there some kind of kerberos refresh interval (similar to group policy refresh)?

I know it becomes active for sure when the computer reboots, also I am aware of the `klist -lh 0 -li 0x3e7 purge` trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When and only when a new access token is created. This does not occur when a TGT is refreshed at 10 hours. It also does not occur automatically when the ticket expires after 7 days. You have to actually get a brand new one. This is why you must either reboot *or* do the klist trick.